# How embed in my page a website with an iframe in apostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I want embed a form that is located in other site, I've seen https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/modules/apostrophe-oembed but the documentation doesn't provide any example how to use that module.

Can I use apostrophe-oembed as a widget?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official [custom widgets tutorial](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets).

What you'll want to do is add a single schema field, `url`, with the `type` setting set to `url`. In `lib/modules/iframe-widgets/index.js` you might write:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'url',
      type: 'url',
      required: true
    }
  ]
};
```

Then, in `lib/modules/iframe-widgets/views/widget.html`, just output your iframe:

```
<iframe src="{{ data.widget.url }}"></iframe>
```

That should be it! Now you can include it in a page template like any other widget:

```
{# Would work just as well in apos.area #}
apos.singleton(data.page, 'someName', 'iframe', {})
```